# Add index in existing index in magento2

Tags: magento2, database, search, mysql-indexes

I want to add an index to an existing index using Setup/UpgradeSchema:

```
 $connection = $setup->getConnection();
        $tableName = $setup->getTable('sales_order_grid');
        $indexName = 'sales_ordergrid_netsuite_id';
        $columnName = 'netsuite_id';

        $connection->addIndex(
            $tableName,
            $indexName,
            $columnName,
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
        );
```

It's creating new insted of adding to existing index.
How can I add an index in existing("FTI_65B9E9925EC58F0C7C2E2F6379C233E7") index?

[image]

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

To add a new column to an existing full-text index in Magento using the Setup/UpgradeSchema, you can follow these steps:

- Create a new file for your database schema upgrade (if you haven't already). This should be located in your custom module's **Setup** directory. The file name should follow the format **UpgradeSchema.php**.
- In the **UpgradeSchema.php** file, you can use the **addIndex()** method along with the **$indexType** parameter set to **AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT**. However, you need to pass an array of columns to the **$columnName** parameter instead of a single column name.
  Here's how you can modify your code to add a new column to the existing full-text index:

enter code here

```
<?php
   namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Setup;

   use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;

   class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
   {
      public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
      {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1', '<')) {
           $connection = $setup->getConnection();
           $tableName = $setup->getTable('sales_order_grid');
           $indexName = 'FTI_65B9E9925EC58F0C7C2E2F6379C233E7';
           $columnName = 'new_column';

           $connection->addIndex(
              $tableName,
              $indexName,
              [$columnName],
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
        );
    }

    $setup->endSetup();
  }
}
```

Replace **[Vendor][Module]** with the appropriate namespace of your custom module. Also, modify the version number **'2.0.1'** to the version from which you want to apply this schema upgrade.

This way, the new column **$columnName** will be added to the existing full-text index identified by **$indexName**. Remember to adjust the **$columnName** to match the column you want to add to the index.

Answer (score 0):

Create one file Setup/Patch/Schema/AddNewIndex.php in your extension.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Schema;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\SchemaPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class AddNewIndex implements SchemaPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    public function __construct(ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup)
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();
        
        $tableName = $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('your_table_name'); // Replace with the table name you want to add the index to
        $indexName = 'your_new_index_name'; // Replace with a unique index name
        $fieldName = 'your_column_name'; // Replace with the column name you want to add an index to
        
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->addIndex(
            $tableName,
            $indexName,
            $fieldName,
            ['type' => Table::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX]
        );
        
        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();

        $tableName = $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('your_table_name');
        $indexName = 'your_new_index_name';

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->dropIndex($tableName, $indexName);

        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting this error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'INDEX_TYPE_INDEX' in  Order/Setup/Patch/Schema/AddNewIndex.php:30

Comment: you need to add a table name where INDEX_TYPE_INDEX is defined.